# How to mock an interface property with JustMock in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, interface, mocking, telerik, justmock

I am using JustMock to mock interfaces for unit testing, but perhaps I'm not doing it right.

I have an interface:

```
Public Interface IFoo
    Property Bar as int
End Interface
```

I want to mock this interface and set that property so that it can be read by consumers of the interface.
Beginning with:

```
Dim mockFoo as IFoo = Mock.Create(Of IFoo)()
```

The I've tried to set the property like this:

```
mockFoo.Bar = 1
```

And also like this:

```
Mock.Arrange(Sub() mockFoo.Bar = 1).DoNothing()
```

<del>and also like this:</del>

<del>Mock.Arrange(Function() mockFoo.Bar).Returns(1)</del>

I followed the question and answer from this post on the Telerik forum (not my question):
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/justmock/general-discussions/mock-property-set-in-vb-net-module.aspx

But the example posted by Telerik doesn't solve my issue. It also looks like a concretion, not an interface. Am I approaching this completely the wrong way?

**EDIT, UPDATE:**
The issue was my project not building. I am able to get interface properties using the following syntax:

```
Mock.Arrange(Function() mockFoo.Bar).Returns(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Mock.Arrange( () => mockFoo.Bar ).Returns(1);
```

See Telerik's documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-mock-returns.html

Comment: Just realized that's C# syntax I used in the lambda, and VB.NET might be different (I haven't used VB.NET much). Is the VB.NET syntax `Sub()` instead of `()`?

Comment: This isn't working for me. In VB.NET I can lambda returns using `Function()` rather than `()` but the property always returns null/nothing.

Comment: @Matthew can you post your test that fails? The syntax looks correct.

Comment: The problem was that my test project wasn't being rebuilt. Using the `Function()` expression I am able to make it work now. Thanks!